# CSS/JS - Fixed top bar interferes with scroll to input field on form invalidity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working with form validation.
[Basic Form Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kOPG.png)

Whenever a form is submitted where the input has the "required" attribute, a hint appears.

Problem is that fixed elements are not taken into account when the jump to the input field happens (which is the correct behaviour)

And since I am using a fixed header, the input field is hidden underneath it.

How to solve this problem so that the fixed navigation bar is taken into account?

For additional context see my fiddle:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #bbb;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<form>
Name: <input type="text" required>
<input type="submit" style="margin-top: 30rem; width: 100%;" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
```

PS: The CSS property "z-index" is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Give those elements **z-index:100;**

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in form, then delete the overflow: hidden in .navbar style.
Add style for form class as below.

Is this what you expected?
This is link about z-index : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_z-index.asp

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
    
.formClass {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<form class="formClass" action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required />
    <input
    type="submit"
    style="margin-top: 30rem; width: 100%"
    value="Submit"
    />
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe I was not precise enough with my question, but z-index this is not what I want. I want the "scroll to invalid input field" to take my navigation into account, so that I dont have to scroll up in order to see the input field. But this might be more of a JS related matter.